# text with hover div element pushes text out of place even after dic collapses

Tags: css, hover, mouseover

I have a div element linked to the anchor text that drops down, pushes the remaining text away and shows content. Moving the mouse from the link makes the element collapse.

The problem is that is that the text after the link is pushed both when hovering over it and after it has collapsed, leaving he text with gaps unless the whole page is reloaded. In safari it doesn't work, but in Chrome it does.

I also can't seem to get the div element to hover over the text without pushing the content. I've tried z-index.

Code snippet. IT seems to run fine in here, but not in my local web-browser. I run it with jekyll.

```css
.thumb {
    position: relative; /*used to be relative*/
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    overflow: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted $highlight-color;
}
.thumb img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.thumb > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; /* used to be absolute: the box covered the link text*/
    overflow: hidden; /* hidden: removes the extra step with all the text vertical*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 0;
    color: $highlight-color;
}
.thumb:hover > div {
    display: inline;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    opacity: 1.0;
    position: relative; /*relative, absolute, relative pushes the content*/
}
.thumb > div div {
    padding: 20px 40px;
}
.thumb h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.thumb p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
&nbsp;<div class="thumb"><a href="{{baseurl}}">Link text</a><div><div>
            <h2>Definition</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
        </div></div></div>&nbsp;
slkdj is het begin van de tekst na de link hover element. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

[Before hover over (and how it should look like after the element collapses)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFXoI.png)
[Div element expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up1Ra.png)
[The text after the link has now a break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P51E.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you add some sample html too?

Comment: Sorry, I added Css and HTML

Comment: As you said _'IT seems to run fine in here'_. Could you please create a snippet or JSFriddle with all styles that create final result in your environment? I see capital letter "L" at the beggining, different text formatting and so on.